# default value in Django model when no value is provided

Tags: django-models

I have a small doubt about the use of default in a model, even after have reading the documentation.

Example Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And trying to use it:

```
Company.objects.create(name='Test')
```

Error Message:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "active" of relation "company" violates not-null constraint
```

If I'm telling Django that the DEFAULT value of this field is False, should it not use False when I don't provide a value?